# CSS not included into the index.html

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader

I have a few css rules and one of them is:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [{ loader: 'style-loader/url' }, { loader: 'file-loader' }],
    include: [require.resolve('normalize.css')],
  },
```

This rule is very specific and matches only single import i.e. inside my `index.js` I have an import:

```
import 'normalize.css';
```

When I build (with WebPack 4) I see in the output `index.html` multiple:

```
<link href="/2.03ec883f8c956db4d531.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/0.6e0b40d9554f38994c59.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

for other css rules, but there is no reference to `normalize.css` bundle. It is available in `dist` folder with the file name of `fda27b856c2e3cada6e0f6bfeccc2067.css` (nicely minimized, and this file contains only normalize.css) , but this `fda27b856c2e3cada6e0f6bfeccc2067.css` is not referenced anywhere inside `index.html`.

How can I fix it?